# Why won't a .mpg video load into pygame's movie module

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, pygame, mpeg

I've been trying to get a short video to load and play within a pygame window. However, the program stalls when it tries to load the video.  I'm also unable to abort the debugger.

```
import pygame
import pygame.movie

pygame.init()

print('TEST')

video = pygame.movie.Movie('D:\\Presentation\\video.mpg')

print('TEST')
```

This outputs 'TEST' once, so the video has not loaded (It keeps running "pygame.movie.Movie('D:\Presentation\video.mpg')" indefinitely).

I let it run for an hour but no luck, it keeps loading without any kind of exception or visible progress and the video is 1,636 KB large, 4 seconds long and was converted from a .mp4 using ffmpeg.

The directory is certainly correct for I tested with images in the same directive. I also restarted my PC (Windows 8.1 64-bit Python 3.2.5.1).

EDIT: I need an answer that will be relevant to the pygame module

Comment: File support is very limited so use FFmpeg as seen [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/movie.html).

Comment: I have used FFmpeg on the video file already.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Pyglet and follow the code I create [here](http://repl.it/rQn) that plays a video.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not helpful, I need to be able to do this all within the pygame module.

Comment: @Frogboxe Can you share a link to download your video and I'll create a program?